# How to convert line breaks into codes?

Tags: php, php-5.3, line-breaks

How can I convert line breaks into codes? For instance,

```
$array = array(
    'title' => 'abc',
    'content'  => 'a paragraph

    line break

    line break

    '
);
```

I want to convert `$array['content']` to

```
a paragraph\r\n\t\r\n\tline break\r\n\t\r\n\tline break\r\n\t\r\n\t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines?

```
$array['content'] = str_replace(array("\n", "\t"), array('\r\n', '\t'), $array['content']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
echo addcslashes($array['content'],"\n\r\t");
```

(If you intend to keep the line feeds as your original example).